# Can someone please identify this 2x2 round dome part with 1 stud for us?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

We're trying to identify the middle part in this picture. We would appreciate any help we can get.

[image: part image]

Answer (score 10):

It looks like a [Round 2 x 2 Dome Top (553b)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=553b&C=1) brick with a [Round 1 x 1 (4073)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4073&C=12) transparent plate.

Comment: To be specific, it is likely 553b (open stud with axle holder).

Comment: I'm not to sure, It looks like it could be 553(a) or 553(b) but not 553(c), They stopped using 553(a) in 2009 so it might not be that depending on how old these pieces are.

Comment: I can clearly make out an 'x' shaped axle hole (not a '+' shaped one). Leads me to believe it is 553b.